# Selecting subnets for a Service in Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, subnet, vpc

[image]

As we can see in the picture above, I can select as many subnets as I want. Does it mean, the tasks in the service are created across these two subnets?

Suppose I have one task running, in which subnet will it run then?
If there are multiple tasks in the service, how are they distributed between these subnets? Is it something handled by Fargate and we shouldn't worry about?

What if I select a public subnet and a private subnet, I'm guessing it would be a mess in that case.

Sorry if these are noob questions, I'm new to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean, the tasks in the service are created across these two subnets?

Yes.

> Suppose I have one task running, in which subnet will it run then?

Random subnet.

> What if I select a public subnet and a private subnet, I'm guessing it would be a mess in that case.

Yes, your tasks could be distributed in both.